# Counting associations where child model's attribute = x

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Trying to get a count of Driver's cars when manual transmission = true. (Driver has_many cars; Car belongs_to driver, etc.)

My current code:

```
<% @driver = Driver.find(1) %>
<% driver.cars.where("Car.manual = true").count %>
```

Returns this error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "car"
LINE 1: ...ars"  WHERE "cars"."driver_id" = $1 AND (Car.m...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "cars"  WHERE "cars"."driver_id" = $1 AND (Car.manual= true)
```

When I remove the ".count", it does seem to find a relationship, because it prints:

```
#<Car::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fea6ddf4c88>
```

I also tried

```
<%= @driver.cars.where(manual = true).count %>
```

But that returns a count of all the driver's cars.

I suspect the problem is with my "manual = true" syntax, but I'm fairly new to writing queries so I'm probably missing something stunningly obvious. If anyone can help me figure out where I'm going wrong, I'd appreciate it. (Or, of course, if there's a better way to do this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Driver` class should declare the relationship:

```
class Driver
  has_many :cars
   # other things
end
```

And then, you have to pass a hash to the `where` conditions:

```
 <%= @driver.cars.where(manual => true).count %>
```

or using the new ruby hash syntax:

```
<%= @driver.cars.where(manual: true).count %>
```

You can always debug the query being sent to the database with

```
<%= @driver.cars.where(manual: true).to_sql %>
```